# CodeIgniter routing: Passing parameter before controller and catching it on the default_controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I'm using a site wide parameter that controls the layout of the website. This parameter goes before anything else in the URL and is followed by the usual *controller/parameters* sections.

```
mywebsite/{section}/controller/parameter1/parameter2
```

I could define routes like the one bellow for each controller, but would like to avoid it as the *section* parameter is only relevant to the layout and not to the controllers.

```
$route['(:any)/controller/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'controller/$2/$3/$1';
```

Instead I would to be able to make the default_controller catch the first segment and store it as a view variable or session / cookie, so that the rest of the controllers can simply ignore it.

```
$route['(:any)/controller/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'controller/$2/$3';
```

Comment: Are you saying the user clicks on the link with {section} in it, but ends up on the link without it?

Comment: why don't you use session or cookie to store the *section* variable per user?

Comment: I don't need to alter the URL in the browser, I just need what I explained happening behind the curtains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Hashem Qolami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1725764/hashem-qolami) said, this is something much better served with a [session](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) or [cookie](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html).

Routing in CodeIgniter does not alter URL's. It allows you to alter what CI does with the URL. You can use server-side functionality to do what you want (e.g. apache rewrites, nginx conf's, etc) but that is out of scope here.

---

Edit:

To do what you want without changing the URL, you can just pass the value to the view:

Controller:

```
$layout = $this->uri->segment(1);
$data["layout"] = $layout;
$this->load->view("cool_view", $data);
```

cool_view.php:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $layout; ?>.css">
```

Comment: Perhaps my question was misleading, I don't need to change what the user sees in the browser, I just need what I explained to be happening inside CI.

Comment: Updated the answer. Be wary of passing user input to a view (even if CI is stingy about what it allows in a URI). Session or cookie is still the better way to handle this.

Comment: Yes. Every controller extends the main controller, so I'm thinking I could add the code there and use the session instead of the view variable.